# How to return multiple columns when using "group by"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following data:

```
itemID  catID   score     age
  1       1        9       5   
  2       1       10       7
  3       1        5      10
  4       2       18      11
  5       2       15      15
```

I want to return the age column, for the maximum score of each category:

```
 catID    score    age
   1       10       7   
   2       18      11
```

I have the following query:

```
select catID, max(score)
from items
group by catID
```

But I don't know how to include the age column as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're after here isn't aggregation on `score` but the details of the person with the highest score. You can use a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve this:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT catID,
           score,
           age,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY catID ORDER BY score DESC) AS RN
    FROM items)
SELECT catID,
       score,
       age
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

If multiple people could have the same score, and you want to return them all, replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: You are first, I'll delete my answer in a minute, +1)

Comment: Haha, beat you by a whole 7 seconds, @Zhorov ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need a join on the subqiery for amx score

```
    select i.catID, i.score, i.age
    from   items i
    INNER JOIN  (
        select catID, max(score) score 
        from items
        group by catID

        ) t on t.catID = i.CatID and t.score = i.score
```